# Can't build ios app with AWS sdk 1.2.0

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services

Can anyone help me? I can't fix this error when building an ios app with aws sdk.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GHTestCase", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_STSTests in AWSiOSSDK(STSTests.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GHTestCase", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_STSTests in AWSiOSSDK(STSTests.o)
  "_GHComposeString", referenced from:
      -[STSTests testGetSessionToken] in AWSiOSSDK(STSTests.o)
      -[STSTests testGetFederatedSessionToken] in AWSiOSSDK(STSTests.o)
```

Comment: is the aws library linked in your application?

Comment: Yes. I actually just updated the library to the latest version then it doesn't work now.

Comment: Hmmm, are you saying that it all worked before updating the library?

Comment: Maybe a problem with GHUnitIOS.Framework?  Anyway, I'll quit guessing, but just looks like linker probs - doesn't now what GHTestCase is...

Comment: Yup. I downloaded the latest sdk and followed the instructions on 'Including the AWS SDK for iOS in Existing Applications' in the http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/mobile/sdkforios/gsg/Welcome.html?r=503

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the GHUnitIOS.Framework. I added that, linked it and I was able to compile. It's weird that the sample projects doesn't need that framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add and link with the GHUnitIOS.Framework.